# Retain Talkback focus within a fragment when returning from another fragment?

Tags: android, accessibility

When using Talkback (screen reader), I focus on an element within one fragment, then navigate to a new fragment. When I return back to the first fragment using the soft, menu back button (up navigation), focus is reset to the first element on the first fragment. Although when using the android system back button, focus is retained on the first fragment. I want focus retained for both instances

Comment: Kindly post snippet that does this.

Comment: What do you mean ? I just go to next fragment using fragment manager, I don't add any special code

Comment: @Thaer Have you found any solution to this issue?